# Suggestions appearing only once for the same text in watched tags

Tags: bug, tag-watching

So, first search for the text **angular** in the tags bar, like I have shown below in the image.

[image]

Now, select **angular** from the list and click on <kbd>Add</kbd>.

Now the textbox will be cleared. Search for the same text again, "angular", and no result will appear. I think this is the issue.

I do not know if this is a real issue or not. Let me know if you have the same issue.

Browser: Chrome version 74.0

Note: on reloading the page its working fine.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this issue on Firefox Nightly 69.0a1.

Comment: Can you try chrome 74.0?

Comment: Unable to repro on Win 10 + Chrome 74 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cHHx.png

Comment: @SamuelLiew try with too many tags? I am still getting an issue

Comment: I managed to repro in win 10 + Chrome 74, but only with sponsored tags. Refreshing the page is a work around

Comment: @NickA yup, refreshing page works for me too

Comment: I could *sort of* repro on macOS 10.14.5 + FF Quantum 67.0. If I type "angular", wait for the popup, add angular, and type "angular" again, no popup. But if I backspace to "angula", the popup shows. Now I refresh the page and restart. If I type fast "angular" enough and hit enter, not letting the popup appear, the popup will appear the next time I type "angular". Could repro with other tags: .net, javascript, stack-overflow.

Comment: @TrebledJ Yes, but it should appear. As I said user selects angularjs first time and then second time if user wants to select angular2 it will not be able to.